# Example of Mandelbrot Set with Holoviews Library is not Showing the Image

Tags: python, pandas, image, bokeh, holoviews

I ran this example code from Holoviews, but it does not generate the image and it doesn't give any errors. Anyone knows why the image is not showing? Here is the link of the code: http://holoviews.org/gallery/apps/bokeh/mandelbrot.html

Comment: Are you running it in Jupyter or in some other way?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @James A. Bednar Thank you for the quick comment. Yes, I am running the code on Jupyter notebook. It does not generate the image, so I was wondering what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HoloViews examples in examples/gallery/apps/bokeh/ are Bokeh apps that can be served by saving them to a .py file like `app.py` and then running `bokeh serve app.py`. To use them in Jupyter, you can delete the lines starting with `doc` (not used in Jupyter) and instead add code at the end to install the Jupyter support and select which object to display:

```
hv.extension("bokeh")
dmap
```

That's clearly not obvious, so please open an issue at https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews/issues to ask for those examples to be better documented!